# Why Is the slick slider refreshing the css of the slider item on the second iteration of loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, slick.js

I am using slick slider as an image carousal.

I added a top position css to one of the child item as given below. The top position css works fine on first load and when the second iteration of the loop starts the top position css is removed and again added in a second which makes a jumping effect. The problem is recreated and showed in the Fiddle given below. Is there any way to fix this jumping issue of the slide?

Problem recreated in this

```js
$(function(){
$('.my-pics').slick({
         infinite: true,
         arrows: true,
         dots: false,
         autoplay: false,
         slidesToShow: 5,
         slidesToScroll: 5,
     });
});
```

```css
.my-pics {
  padding: 18% 4%;
}
.my-pics .slick-list {
  overflow: visible;
}
.my-pics .slick-list .slick-slide {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.my-pics .slick-list .slick-slide a {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.my-pics .slick-list .slick-slide a img {
  display: block;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
.my-pics .slick-list .slick-slide:nth-child(7) {
  top: -90px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.js"></script>

<div class="slider-wrapper">
<ul class="my-pics">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think if you are doing an infinite loop, once the item gets to the end, it is appended to the beginning and therefore will no longer be the 7th child.  Your best off putting a class on that slide and styling that instead

Comment: How can i add class to that specific item?

Comment: put it on the li?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
$('.my-pics').slick({
         infinite: true,
         arrows: true,
         dots: false,
         autoplay: false,
         slidesToShow: 5,
         slidesToScroll: 5,
     });
});
```

```css
.my-pics {
  padding: 18% 4%;
}
.my-pics .slick-list {
  overflow: visible;
}
.my-pics .slick-list .slick-slide {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.my-pics .slick-list .slick-slide a {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.my-pics .slick-list .slick-slide a img {
  display: block;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
//I deleted this line in your code and it works fine
/*.my-pics .slick-list .slick-slide:nth-child(7) {
  top: -90px;
}*/

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.js"></script>

<div class="slider-wrapper">
<ul class="my-pics">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/307c4d415928020c567f6011288be180/5B7CBC15/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30087758_2087929068157950_662421103938895872_n.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: :- Thanks for your answer. As per your suggestion when i remove the "top: - 90px" CSS all images will be in line. But what i need is to make that image always show in the top with out  jumping while looping. Hope you got my point.